# adding scope in google calendar through REST api

Tags: c#, google-api, google-calendar-api, google-oauth, google-api-dotnet-client

while creating a project,i have added scope for google drive. Now i want to use the same clientid and secretid for accessing the google calendar. It shows 403 forbidden error as there is no scope for google calendar, Now i want to add that scope using rest api with c#. How to add the scope after once configured?

Comment: While I am able to understand your question others may not.  Its best if you post your code and the full error message that you are getting returned.  This will increase the chance your question may help someone else in the future.

Answer (score 0):

first go to google developer console and enable google calendar as well.

Your code probably looks something like this.  scopes is just a string array

```
static string[] Scopes = { DriveService.Scope.Drive, DriveService.Scope.Calendar };
```

Will request both drive and calendar scopes.

You are going to need both a driveservice and a clendarservice to interact with the different apis.

Your users will need to re-authenticate your application to add the new scope to their credentials.

Comment: I want to have in api call this scope. I am not using sdk .  So through rest api i want to update it